# Is it necessary to use Rampart on client if server is using it?

Tags: apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

I'm developing a web service and I am working with Axis2 + Rampart on the server. Is it necessary to have Rampart on both ends of the web service? Or is it possible to have a client which implements WS-Security with something other than Rampart?

The examples of Rampart which I've found seem to assume Rampart on both ends. I can't tell if that's just convenient, or if it's necessary. I don't have any control over the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not necessary to use Rampart on the client. Rampart is basically processing the security headers in the SOAP message according to the WS-Security* Specifications. So if the client can send valid SOAP messages containing standard security headers adhering to the WS-Security* Specifications, rampart will successfully process the request and validate security.